# LocalDate MySQL persistence comes back the date before

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, java-8, jpa-2.0

I have seen this question posted a few times on StackOverflow, and it has been with mostly Spring Boot apps with Spring Boot Configuration.   I've followed all the steps, and I still have this issue.  If I can't get this resolved soon, I will have to go back to the old java.util.Date in order to persist my data to the database ... at least it worked without issues.  So, I have a Spring 5.1.2.Release app, with Hibernate 5.4.0.Final, the hibernate-java8 dependency, and the latest MySQL Connector 8.0.13.

I understand from previous posts and other articles on the Net that if the database is set for UTC, but the App is running in another timezone, in my case GMT-5 for EST, then this problem might pop up.

So, here are the technical details:
My MySQL connection looks like:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db? 
serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true
```

The connection string, is used in the applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.driver.class}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${hibernate.connection.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My Hibernate properties in my applicationContext.xml look like:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">${hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer}</prop>
            <prop key="useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="useLegacyDatetimeCode">false</prop>
            <prop key="serverTimezone">UTC</prop>
            <prop key="useTimezone">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone">UTC</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

My Maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Entity Code is simple:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private long txId;

@Column(name = "transaction_date")
private LocalDate txDate;
```

I save my code to the database like this:

```
@Override
public TxEntity create(TxEntity txEntity)
{
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(txEntity);
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().refresh(txEntity);
    return txEntity;
}
```

The database has "transaction_date" as a DATE field in MySQL.

My Unit Test shows that I can create a new record, and I have set the date as follows:

```
      LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

I persist the record, and when I test:

```
assertEquals(today, myRecord.getTransactionDate());
```

this fails, because I get the previous date.

I thought that if I used the latest versions of Hibernate and the Hibernate-java8 I would be fine, but that's not the case.   I thought if I pulled in the latest JPA2.2 that would work, but it's not.  So, I think I am doing everything right, and I still have an issue.

So, if there is anything you need to see, let me know and I can add it.  I think I am doing everything right, but if there is anything off I need to fix, please let me know.    And of course, I'll keep looking at this myself.

Comment: Spring 4 doesn't officially support Hibernate 5.4 (afaik) so you might want to reconsider. Also the `java8` types are part of `hibernate-core` since hibernate 5.2 so ou don't need the additional dependency. You set the `hibernate.connection.url` but I don't see anywhere where you use this URL. If you use that to configure hibernate to use the connection but also injecting a manually configured datasource the setting is pretty much doing nothing. In short there is too little config information to see if you are configuring the right things.

Comment: I also mis the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` property being set to `UTC` in your hibernate configuration. Also see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/

Comment: @M.Deinum   I just added where I use the connection string, it's right there in the applicationContext.xml file ... what else don't you see that might help.   I can always move this application to Spring 5 ... I am not a fan of Spring Boot.

Comment: Property name was misleading. None the less you should have the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` property in your hibernate properties and that is missing. See the linked article in my previous comment which explains all that.

Comment: @M.Deinum  my mistake, this is not Spring Boot, but it is using Spting 5.1.2.Release

Comment: Again you are missing the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` property in your configuration. See the earlier linked article.

Comment: @M.Deinum  added the missing property ... no change!   And yes, I read the article.   I actually tried that property last night  and there was no change, and I did read the article.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-properties-changed.html which clarifies that `useLegacyDatetimeCode` has been removed. Not sure what the replacement is.

Comment: According to one of the hibernate developers it might be a bug. Could create a small sample to reproduce the issue and create an issue in the [hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch your Java project or connection strings to solve this issue you can configure the MySQL timezone directly. On my computer the JVM timezone was correct (America/Sao_Paulo), so changing it to UTC in order to solve this conflict with MySQL was a no go.

The problem I had was just at the MySQL timezone configuration. Since I run MySQL on a container it got a wrong default timezone. The fix was to pass the `--default-time-zone=America/Sao_Paulo` to the MySQL container configuration, which fixed this issue. Now both MySQL and JVM got the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after some debugging for some time, I noticed Mysql timezone was UTC, but my default jvm timezone which can be seen by:

```
public class DefaultTimeZone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    }
}
```

was America/Montreal so in updated my ide (IntellJ) settings to pass -Duser.timezone=UTC as a parameter when starting the application. (Of course there are so many other ways to do this, but in my case this was enough)